# How can I find a common factor of two polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have some lecture notes here and they magically find (x-1) to be a common factor of $x^3-3x+2$  and  $x^3-x^2-x+1$.

I'm wondering whether I'm missing something or the lecture notes are just weak?

Thanks!

Comment: Something is wrong with your first polynom.

Comment: Shoot its supposed to be a minus, Apolgoies & Thanks!

Comment: How aabout now?

Comment: Do you know the rational root theorem?

Comment: No I don't. I'm a first year is it something that will come in handy?

Comment: It is a useful thing in pre-calculus classes. What is the context for this problem? Just to find the factors?

Comment: Useful as it is, you don't have to know the roots in order to find the common factor.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't recall saying that you did.

Comment: Right. So I'm trying to apply find the limit tending to 1 of the aforementioned polynomials divided but that tends to 0/0. Which means I need to simplify the polynomials before I can find the limit & they've somehow gotten that common factor!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense why you are asking this question.  If you have a calculator handy, I'd just plot that fraction and see how it looks.  If it doesn't do anything weird, most likely there is a common factor.

Comment: Well, if a polynomial turns to 0 at $x=1$, it must have a factor of $(x-1)$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I feel so ashamed that it was that easy! Wow! xD

Comment: What you are looking for is the Euclidean algorithm for finding the greatest common factor of two numbers or polynomial.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Hold up, I can do this for polynomials?!  =D

Comment: @ReneSchipperus How do I go about doing that? or do you have video tutorial you can point me to?

Comment: Yeah just look it up somewhere, a number theory book or Wikipedia. It is exactly the same for polynomials as for numbers.

Comment: Cheers everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a greatest common divisor for polynomials. The only caution I would add is that this need not have integer coefficients; it is by nature a polynomial with rational coefficients.

$$ \gcd(x^3 - 3 x + 2, x^3 - x^2 - x + 1) $$
first minus second replaces second
$$ \gcd(x^3 - 3 x + 2,  x^2 -2 x + 1) $$
first minus $(x+2)$ times second replaces first
$$ \gcd(0,  x^2 -2 x + 1) $$ 
$$  x^2 - 2 x + 1  $$

Comment: Man, I remember discovering this in elementary school, and the feeling when you find it works for polynomials!

Comment: I don't understand the "first minus second replaces second" part, how did the $x^3$ dissapear from the second polynomial? Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$
x^3-3x+2=x^3-x-2x+2=x(x^2-1)-2(x-1)=
$$ 
$$
=x(x-1)(x+1)-2(x-1)=(x-1)[x(x+1)-2]=(x-1)(x^2+x-2)
$$
and:
$$
x^3-x^2-x+1=x^2(x-1)-1(x-1)=(x-1)(x^2-1)=(x-1)^2(x+1)
$$

Comment: The first polynomial has a second factor of $(x-1)$.

Comment: Indeed $ x^2 + x-2 = (x-1)(x+2)$

Comment: Yes, anyway to answer the question it suffice to show that $x-1$ is a common factor.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$P(x)=x^3-3x+2$$
$$=x^3-x-2(x-1)$$

$$=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)-2(x-1)$$

$$=(x-1)(x^2+x-1)$$
$$=(x-1)(x-\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2})(x-\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$$

and
$$Q(x)=x^3-x^2-x+1$$
$$=x^2(x-1)-(x-1)$$

$$=(x-1)(x^2-1)=(x-1)^2(x+1)$$

from here, we see that $(x-1)$, is the only common factor.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Polynomial Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem). This theorem says that $f(a) = 0$ if and only if $x - a$ is a factor of $f(x)$, for polynomial $f(x)$.

The fact that both polynomials approach $0$ as $x \to 1$ suggests that they both share the common zero $x = 1$, and so must share the common factor $(x - 1)$. To keep evaluating the limit, you would factor $(x - 1)$ out of each with polynomial long or synthetic division.

Comment: Note: Both actually have a *second* factor of $(x - 1)$ in common; after factoring the first out and cancelling, you would find the fraction still has the indeterminate $\frac00$ form, again suggesting that the remaining polynomials have a common zero $x = 1$ and a common factor of $(x -1)$. But now they'll be quadratics, and you can just factor by hand to get things out of the indeterminate $\frac00$ form.

Comment: This is what I had completely missed! xD So embarrassing but now I'm intrigued to see how everybody else is doing it without this theorem.

Comment: @K.M. Worry not :) What you are seeing is a bit of what's to come, if you keep taking math courses. While not exactly more sophisticated than calculus, it's the sort of thing students (in the US at least) don't really see until college, and even then not in "standard" courses like Calculus.

Comment: I'm actually in my first year of university in the UK so I should know this as well as I know my date of birth ;D